# creating timelapse from still images (jpg) to mp4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, timelapse

I have tried a number of different options found on StackExchange for converting still images into an mp4. I have yet to be entirely successful. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ffmpeg -i ../*.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -y output.mp4
```

The resulting mp4 contains the first image with 00:00 for the length of the video. It looks like it is working. The stream mapping shows all 17 images (0-16) in the Stream mapping. I see in the output text that it determined the image resolution to be 1280x800, which is correct.

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but the initial images are around 93KB. The mp4 is 504KB.

These 17 images are part of a test set. Eventually, I hope to use this method to generate a 6-day time-lapse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Problem

`ffmpeg` expands the `*` wildcard in your command to:

```
ffmpeg -i 001.jpg 002.jpg 003.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -y output.mp4
```

This assumes your input files are named `001.jpg`, `002.jpg`, `003.jpg`, etc.

So now `001.jpg` is the only input and `002.jpg`, `003.jpg`, `output.mp4` are the output files. Since you're using the dangerous `-y` option (automatically overwrite without asking) then `002.jpg` and `003.jpg` have been overwritten.

## Solutions

Use the `-pattern_type glob` option:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -c:v libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4
```

This may not work in Windows.

Or tell it the inputs are a sequence. For `001.jpg`, etc:

```
ffmpeg -i %03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4
```

For `image-0001.jpg`, etc:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i image-%04d.jpg -c:v libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4
```

Or add a `cat`:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -framerate ntsc -i - -c:v libx264 -crf 0 output.mp4
```

For more info see the [image demuxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).

Comment: A possible gotcha: When reading files from stdin it's the **actual** file content which should be piped, not a list of filenames. I know that's what the command does, but I must have sub-consciously assumed it was the list of names.

Comment: That combination worked perfectly for me.  However, the video was somewhat jittery.  Every so often one image would stay longer on the screen before the video would resume normal speed.  I used a framerate of 30.  Does anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest output.mp4
```

You can also stretch resulting video/image

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest -vf scale=1280:720 output.mp4
```